# Condition to check second period overlap with first period but if second period is in between first period consider it as not over lap

Tags: conditional-statements

I have two periods of A and B

[image]

In the above image table

I need to show alert only B period overlaps A period but should not show message if Bs period is inbetween A's period

Comment: Why is this tagged with Javascript and Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the conditional should look something like the following pseudo code:

```
if(b.fromDate>=a.fromDate&&b.toDate<=a.toDate)
    then show message in between
else
    overlap
```

P.S. you need to state definition of overlap and in between much  more clearly to get a better answer.